# Task scheduler to restart a program when GPU temps are high

Tags: gpu, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I am running multiple GPUs in my system for mining and used MSI afterburner to set the overclocks. I have identified an issue where one of GPU gets non optimized once the ambient temp of my room rises. I am able to optimize it by clicking on the overclock profile which I had set in MSI afterburner however I do not want to do it manually all the time.

Can someone tell me how can I use Task scheduler to simply restart my MSI afterburner if one of the GPU temps get above a certain limit( specified by me) since the programs restarts itself it will automatically apply the set overclocks so that I won't have to worry about the GPU temps anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens with laptops and PC.. To maintain the system functionality.

Lower the Temp to Safe GPU Temperature
When you find your GPU temperature is above the normal GPU temperature, you should try the following solutions to lower it down.

Consider water cooling.
Roll back to previous GPU driver.
Check the air flow (add a larger fan or mount additional fans).
Check ambient temperature and cable management.
Clean dust from heatsink, fan, and other components with a vacuum cleaner or air compressor.
Turn to non-overclocked settings (disable overclocking).
Change the graphical settings of the games you play to a lower level.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for replying however It happens very occassionally and I am not planning to invest more money into it. Would really appreciate if you have any idea about setting up Task scheduler to restart MSI Afterburner after GPU reaches to a certain temp.